# Unable to Repair MariaDB Database Because It Is Read-Only

Tags: mariadb, recovery, corruption

A recent incident corrupted my MariaDB database and I'm trying to repair it. I followed the instructions on the [MariaDB site](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-recovery-modes/) and successfully started my database at `innodb_force_recovery=5`. I have identified the problematic table using `mysqlcheck`. That table is fortunately an unimportant one, so I tried to drop it. But, at recovery level 5, the database is read-only. The MariaDB site recommends backing up the database (which I did), dropping it, and then importing all the data. Again, because the database is read-only, I cannot drop it.

Now I am stuck: to start MariaDB without crashing, I have to set `innodb_force_recovery=5`, which makes the database read-only. Is there a way to circumvent this restriction and delete my database?

Comment: Can you `RENAME TABLE` to move it aside while you reconstruct and populate the desired table?

Comment: @RickJames It seems that under read-only mode the database cannot be modified in any way, and that includes renaming a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A recent incident corrupted my MariaDB database and I'm trying to repair it.

If your car's engine exploded into flames, would you start picking around under the bonnet trying to fix *that*?
Your first instinct should always be to **recover** your database from the Backups that you take for *exactly* that purpose.

You have little or no idea what happened to your database, or its server, or the server's disk, or whatever actually *caused* the "incident", so you have little or no idea what state your "database" is actually in (*regardless* of what mysqlcheck might be telling you).

Do the *sensible* thing - throw this database away and get it back to a known, Good State from your Backups.

> The MariaDB site recommends backing up the database (which I did), dropping it, and then importing all the data. Again, because the database is read-only, I cannot drop it.

- First, you backup the database.
  *Very* fortunately, you *could* in this case but be warned; in other cases, you may not be so lucky!).
- Then - and this is the missing bit - you *reinitialise* the database, obliterating *everything* that was there.
- Then, you restore the backup.

Depending on the *format* of that backup, you may be able to just "edit out" the errant table.  Alternatively, the restore process might complain about it and give you the option to "skip" that table.

Comment: Thanks! I uninstalled MariaDB, deleted all the database files according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640899/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql-completely), and restored a previous dump. Everything is up and running now, though I wish MariaDB's site can give an official guide on obliterating everything in the database.